# material groups are linked with another, how can I unlink them from another?

Tags: materials, node-editor

First I will describe what I have done:

- In node editor, I added material nodes
- I selected material nodes and grouped it
- I duplicated the group
- Then I edited one of them

However, when I edited the duplicated group, the same edits and the same modifications were applied to the original group too.

**My question:** why is this and how can I unlink them?

Answer (score 2):

Click that number next to the group name:
[image]